# How to add different title and description for different pages in Cayman github pages?

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I'm currently using the [Cayman](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman) theme for making GitHub pages. I can understand that there is a default layout. Suppose I want to have a different title and Description within the header for different pages. For instance as shown below
[image]
"Data Collection" is a Title and "It automates....." is a description. Suppose I create another page and want to change this title and description for another how can I do that in this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that theme has some issue with the title.
See "[Title is not working #134](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman/issues/134)"

[Ben Souchet](https://github.com/BenSouchet) adds:

> The only correct solution currently is to "create a custom layout", this is ultra easy and can be done in 1min.
> The steps are:
>
> - On your repo where you have the `_config.yml` file you need to create a folder named "`_layouts/`" and in that new folder create a file named "`default.html`"
> - In that "`default.html`" past the content of this page.
> - Replace this line `<h1 class="project-name">{{ page.title | default: site.title | default: site.github.repository_name }}</h1>` with this line `<h1 class="project-name">{{ site.title | default: site.github.repository_name }}</h1>`
> - And replace this line `<h2 class="project-tagline">{{ page.description | default: site.description | default: site.github.project_tagline }}</h2>` with `<h2 class="project-tagline">{{ site.description | default: site.github.project_tagline }}</h2>`
> - Save the file ("`default.html`")
> - Wait approx 2mins for the build of your page to be fully done
> - Voilà

But that is only for *one* page, which is what that theme is make for.
For multiple pages, you need a different theme.